# Advancing a cell coordinates

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a row of cells that I have extracted from a spreadsheet. I am taking these cells and looping through them. I would like to extract the coordinates of a cell and check another cell in that same column. Is there an easy way to do this outside of separating the coordinate manually?

Here is some example code to give you an idea of what I'm doing:

```
  import openpyxl
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
  ws = wb[sheetName]
  descs    = ws['1']
  for sel in desc:
      coor = sel.coordinates
      # advance coordinate in column and check the value
```

I know I could extract the coordinate, take the string "A1", separate it to be "A" and "1", advance "1" to be "2", and concatenate them to get "A2", but that seems long. Any other solutions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a pretty easy answer, I just didn't look at the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html) very thoroughly. The best way to go about it is to use [offset](https://kite.com/python/docs/openpyxl.cell.Cell.offset). This returns the cell according to an offset of row and column and allows you to be able interact with that cell. there may be other ways as well, but this by far was easiest for my problem.

The code that I added was:

```
  sel.offset(1, 0)
```